# Server doesn't receive more messages from client

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am creating a chat application. The client sends messages to the sever, the server just receives the first message but not more.

**Server reading Thread**

```
private void read(ObjectInputStream ois) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String[] contents = (String[]) ois.readObject();
                MainContainer.gh.add(new JLabel(contents[0] + " : " + contents[1]));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Sorry.");
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**Client write method**

```
public void write(String[] contents) {
    try {
        oos.writeObject(contents);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Sorry");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. If you need extra code, you may request for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code hasn't a loop.

So it receive the first array named `contents` then exit.

You should add a loop similar to this one

```
while (true) {
    // Receive messages
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The server code must run in a loop. From memory, the server thread should run something like this

```
while (running) {
  // block until next request
  Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
  InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
  OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
  // Read from in. Write to out. Your code here...
}
```

`running` is usually a `volatile` variable that may be set to signal from other threads that the program should stop. Or you could interrupt the thread. Also, prepare to let the user configure socket timeouts.

Comment: `String[] contents = (String[]) ois.readObject();` Why this array is not updated? I am receiving updated contents from `ois.readObject()` method but the array has the old contents.